# Ripping DVD to iso - Accurately

Tags: dvd, iso

I have been using Brasero to rip my DVD collection to .iso.  However, I've discovered some errors in some of the DVDs through playback e.g. VLC player would just stop playing the iso file when a bad section in playback is met (half-way through a film).

The worst thing is that no errors or warnings were thrown during the ripping process - I could have .  Is there a method or application that will monitor DVD/file data integrity and avoid such scenarios in the future?

Anything equivalent to Exact Audio Copier or CDparanoia for DVDs?

Comment: I believe EAC and cdparanoia are needed for music CDs because CD-Audio doesn't include the error-correction data in higher-level formats like DVD-Video. It should suffice to just copy the bits directly, as Neojames suggests.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail That's not correct, the [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio#Data_encoding) of a CD has functionality like parity, but there is also functionality in a drive to read a CD less accurate which EAC and cdparanoia disable or force the drive to verify the read data to get accurate results.

Comment: off topic but cdda2wav can use paranoia and should be preferred

Answer (score 78):

I think you can use dd to copy disks well. Using

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=image_name.iso
```

I can confirm it works well with CDs and should work well with DVDs too.

**Edit: I just used this to rip a DVD, so I can confirm it works with DVDs too.**

Comment: Should the DVDs itself be faulty, I can only recommend gddrescue as it will automatically skip over unreadable sectors (the default is to try around thirty times, if I recall correctly, which just takes forever and fails if it does not succeed in reading the disk).

Comment: I can confirm that it works, later burnt with brassero to a new dvd, and they seem identical.

Comment: @sup `ddrescue` tries by default at most two times.

Comment: That did not work, failed with input/output error, though nothing seems to be wrong with the CD.

Comment: Worked for me (for DVD), using: **`sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=image_name.iso`**

Comment: You should really use `isoinfo -d -i /dev/cdrom` to find out the logical block size (almost always 2048) and the number of blocks ("Volume size is" line) on the volume to pass as arguments to dd.  Which makes the dd command look like `dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=2048 count=1621535 of=filename.iso`.

Comment: If you don't tell `dd` when to stop copying, it's going to copy the entire disk up to its full size. So the resulting ISO image file is going to be the same size as the media itself, not the size of the data on the media. In other words, if you have a DVD with only 1GB of data on it, your ISO file will be 4.7GB (or more) in size. If you give `dd` a block size and count as @tgharold mentioned, the resulting ISO file will be only as big as necessary to hold the data on the media.

Comment: the value of `count` in `dd` taken from `isoinfo` is ambiguous. Thus, you can ignore it and just do `dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=2048 of=out.iso`, `dd` will stop once reaching end of the disc.

Comment: If the DVD is copyprotected you'll need to install libdvdcss for VLC, then load it up in VLC before you start trying to rip it or your DVD drive may just refuse to rip it

Comment: @transang can you explain: why is the count output from `isoinfo` ambiguous, and do you mean it stops when reaching the end of the _disc_ or the end of its _contents_? AKA will it always be 4.7GB?

Comment: @Matthias actually, my comment was rather ambiguous. Some CD/DVDs are created with padding (`cdrecord -pad` or `cdrecord -padsize=63s` [link](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/coasterless.htm)) to mitigate the read-ahead buffer in ISO-9660. `isoinfo` returns the size of the disc **without** the padding, causing the copied file being different from the original disc (checksum will fail). If you skip the `count` param in `dd`, it will copy till the end of the disc, including the padding [link](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?296509-isoinfo-and-DVD-image-size).

Comment: @transang so you're saying there's a risk of an inaccurate copy if you pass `dd` a `count` from `isoinfo`?

Comment: @Matthias in a sense, yes. Exactly speaking, you will not be able to confirm the correctness of the copy if you use incorrect `count`. `dd` does not do sumcheck after copy. In practice, checksum is recommended, especially, when the data source/target is CD/DVD. If `isoinfo` returns incorrect `count`, the checksum will always fail, leading to disabling the purpose of the checksum.

Comment: Really, one of the tools mentioned below is best but with dd you can mitigate read errors by adding ```bs=2048 conv=skip``` option, which replaces misread blocks with a block of zero bytes

Comment: Sorry, ```conv=sync```  Der.

Answer (score 39):

I haven't found one link that points to what I believe is a correct answer. Most just say DD the CD/DVD. But there is an extra padding at the end of the media that may cause errors.

I should also point out this will work with most, but I ran into issues with Sony CSS/CPPM Protection, which I used another program to achieve the desired results.

Any, I've found the following to work great for me.. :

1. get the info of the CD/DVD you're copying. I haven't tried this with an audio CD because I just rip them to flac's , but the following is a test on a DVD..

   ```
   # isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr1 | grep -i -E 'block size|volume size'
   Logical block size is: 2048
   Volume size is: 2264834
   ```

   **We use the Logical block size for the BS= variable and Volume size for the COUNT=**
2. use DD to copy the DVD to an iso:

   ```
   # dd if=/dev/sr1 of=/mnt/incoming/test.iso bs=2048 count=2264834
   2264834+0 records in
   2264834+0 records out
   4638380032 bytes (4.6 GB, 4.3 GiB) copied, 373.405 s, 12.4 MB/s
   ```

   To [monitor `dd` progress](https://askubuntu.com/a/215590/349837) one alternative is to add `status=progress`.
3. Test the image against the actual DVD..

   ```
   # md5sum /mnt/incoming/test.iso 
   d3a2cdd58b8c9ade05786526a4a8eae2  /mnt/incoming/test.iso

   # md5sum /dev/sr1
   d3a2cdd58b8c9ade05786526a4a8eae2  /dev/sr1
   ```

Hope this helps someone looking for a complete answer.

Comment: ```isosize -x /dev/sr0``` works also for getting the info

Comment: Note to myself: to dd command line add `status=progress` to watch verbose progress notifications

Answer (score 15):

Use dvdbackup.

Here's how to rip the entire DVD:

```
dvdbackup -i /dev/dvd -o ~ -M
```

That puts the DVD contents into a new subdirectory of your home directory (~). To then generate an .iso, use this command:

```
mkisofs -dvd-video -udf -o ~/dvd.iso ~/[movie_name]
```

If you want, you can alternatively only rip the main feature (see [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dvdbackup) or [sourceforge](http://dvdbackup.sourceforge.net/usage.html) documentation). If you want a video file (e.g. .m4v) instead of an .iso, use [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) after ripping the entire DVD (don't forget to install libdvdcss!).

There are ways to reduce the number of steps, but this seems to be more robust than alternatives.

I've been especially happy with the [archlinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dvdbackup).

P.S. I suspect that most of the answers were excellent at the time of writing, but I found them to be unhelpful at the time I'm writing this, so I thought I'd write an answer that works for me in case others are finding this question around the same time that I did.

Comment: `dvdbackup` brings errors with multiple DVDs that I tried to rip. ("libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in ...". It works for some DVDs, but not all.

Answer (score 13):

You have several options, all work well in GNOME:

- [**AcidRip**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/acidrip) [image: Install acidrip] is an automated front end for MPlayer/Mencoder (ripping and encoding DVD tool using mplayer and mencoder) written in Perl, using Gtk2::Perl for a graphical interface. Makes encoding a DVD just one button click!

  ```
  sudo apt install acidrip
  ```
- [**dvd-rip**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dvdrip) [image: Install dvdrip] is a full featured DVD copy program written in Perl i.e. front end for transcode and ffmpeg. It provides an easy to use but feature-rich Gtk+ GUI to control almost all aspects of the ripping and transcoding process.

  It uses the widely known video processing swissknife transcode and many other Open Source tools. dvd::rip itself is licensed under GPL / Perl Artistic License. You can install dvd::rip as follows under Debian / Ubuntu Linux:

  ```
  sudo apt install dvdrip
  ```
- [**K9copy**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k9copy) [image: Install k9copy] is a KDE DVD Backup tool. It allows the copy of a DVD9 to a DVD5. It is also known as a Linux DVD shrink. It supports the following features: The video stream is compressed to make the video fit on a 4.7GB recordable DVD. DVD Burning. Creation of ISO images. Choosing which audio and subtitle tracks are copied. Title preview (video only). The ability to preserve the original menus.

  ```
  sudo apt install k9copy
  ```

Comment: None of these will rip to an ISO as the original question asked.

Comment: k9copy does, but it's no longer available in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Neither is acidrip, for that matter. :-(

Comment: @JoeyAdams: K9Copy should be available in the [Ubuntu multiverse repository, see this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy).

Answer (score 9):

In case of a strong or weird anti-copy protection and the DVD is yours, you should  decrypt the DVD first and then execute a fault-tolerant copy of it.

Install dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt install libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
$ sudo apt install mplayer gddrescue
```

Decrypt your DVD (assuming the device file is /dev/sr0):

```
$ mplayer -dvd-device /dev/sr0 dvd:// -vo null -ao null -ss 10 -endpos 1
```

Create the image:

```
$ ddrescue -n -b 2048 /dev/sr0 title.iso title.log
```

You can work on the image "title.iso" later on. ddrescue should have skipped garbled content if any.

Comment: This was the only answer that properly ripped a DVD with copy protection; dd and other utilities did not work correctly. I used Ubuntu 16.04 for this (yes, an old distro, but the one installed on my only device with a DVD player).

Comment: I was trying to use ``dd`` and failing. Critical step is decryption with mplayer first

Answer (score 7):

Brasero will accurately copy DVDs. You must first install 'libdvdcss2' from the VLC website. This allows Brasero to defeat the 'CSS' (Content Scramble System) which is used in commercial DVDs to prevent unauthorized copying.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but can you copy a DVD without decrypting?  Essentially making a raw copy of the encrypted disc where the copy is also encrypted?

Comment: @thomasrutter There are no stupid questions.  But the answer is no.  At least not without making your own DVD.  A portion of the key algorithm uses information that's pre-set, even on writeable DVDs.

Comment: @thomasrutter, yes you can. All the bitwise copy methods listed as answers here all do just that such as `dd` and `ddrescue`.

Comment: @Adrian the comment above suggests this is impossible since the encryption is done at a lower level, and even if you could, the data would be useless since decryption requires information pre-baked into the disc which is not read or copied as part of the disc data

Comment: @thomasrutter so you're saying that the bitwise copies are actually copies of the bits under the encryption?

Comment: It seems the decryption is done at a very low level as my attempts to use ``dd`` all failed with ``dd: error reading '/dev/sr0': Input/output error`` until playing with mplayer first.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ddrescue`. I was able to make a bitwise copy of my DVD with the following command with success from a cygwin command prompt:

```bash
ddrescue --no-scrape /dev/scd0 backup.iso
```

A similar command can be used on other variations of *inx.  Of course you would have to download `ddrescue` for your flavour of *inx using the appropriate install app.  See your *inx help pages for details.

Answer (score 4):

> Anything equivalent to Exact Audio Copier or CDparanoia for DVDs?

`dvdisaster` can do multiple passes if a sector is damaged, equivalently to CDparanoia. Example usage:

```
dvdisaster -d /dev/sr0 -i /path/to/output.iso --read-raw -r --read-attempts 5-20
```

It's in Ubuntu's universe repo.

Answer (score 3):

Handbrake is in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake
```

To install the CLI version of Handbrake open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake-cli
```

The results of `snap find handbrake` will usually show that the version of handbrake-jz is the latest stable version of Handbrake. To install this handbrake snap package run these commands:

```
sudo snap install handbrake-jz
```

#### How to Rip DVDs Using HandBrake

1. Open HandBrake.
2. Choose the file you want to rip by selecting the *File* -> *Open Single Title*.
3. Choose the destination to save the stored file by clicking the downward triangle ▼ next to *To:* in the lower right corner and browsing to the destination directory.
4. Click the green *Start* icon at the top to begin ripping the DVD.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkisofs -r -o file.iso /dev/cdrom
```

This is just one example, feel free to check `mkisofs --help` to check all the other options.

Comment: This command does not works for me. It returns: `I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
Total translation table size: 0
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 264
Total directory bytes: 0
Path table size(bytes): 10
Max brk space used 0
175 extents written (0 MB)`

Comment: maybe adding `-l` to the command can help...

Answer (score 2):

I add SimpleBurn (http://simpleburn.tuxfamily.org/ ), a minimalistic free Linux application enabling you to make ISO file from DVD disc easily and quickly. Of course, you will have to install libdvdcss2 in your Linux if you want to extract media content from the copy-protected DVD discs. For more DVD/Blu-ray digitizing tools and knowledge, visit my site at: http://dvd0101.com.

Answer (score 1):

I have extracted to an .iso file with k3b (KDE based tool)

K3b Main Menu -> Tools -> Copy Medium

On the left, check "Create image" if not already checked
and uncheck "Remove image" if it checked.

Click on the Image tab and pick a path for
"Write image file to:"

E.g. "/home/me/tmp/myDvd.iso"

Click "Start"

Then just cancel the copy after the file has been extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `dd` to rip my DVDs in the past, it required `libdvdcss` to work though.

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

Answer (score 1):

[D1g1ta1's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/874945/681688) about using `bs=# count=#` at the end of the `dd` command successfully created 4.6GB .iso files of my 4.6GB DVD (of a Qubes OS 4.0 .iso). However upon calculating the sha256 hash, I found that the contents for some reason turned out different.

Using `dd if=discDrive of=disc.iso`, without parameters, works normally and produces and correct hash values. Before, my drive was acting up and it was producing the wrong hash value; in addition, before, my disc drive was not creating the full 4.6GB iso. I think my drive is just broken.

K3b is a GUI program. I found it successfully creates .iso files and the hashes calculated of the resulting .iso files are correct!

The Brasero program also works and the resulting .iso files are also correct.

Answer (score 1):

There was a previous attempt to provide a "complete" answer, but it did not take CSS copy protection into account. So here's my attempt at a follow-up. I am taking the approach of trying the lightest touch first, and then moving on to increasingly aggressive approaches only as circumstances warrant.

If the DVD does not use CSS (content scramble system) encryption, then the simple dd command recommended in other answers will work.

(All code snippets are borrowed from previous answers)

```
# isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr1 | grep -i -E 'block size|volume size'
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 2264834

# dd if=/dev/sr1 of=backup.iso bs=[Logical Block Size from above] count=[Volume size from above]
```

If the disc does use CSS encryption, but no other tricks such as "fake" bad blocks, then the dd command by itself may not work. This is because the firmware inside most DVD drives will recognize the presence of CSS encryption, and will refuse to allow low-level read access to any sectors that are marked as subject to copyright protection. You must use a program which invokes the DeCSS library (or something equivalent) to "unlock" the disc in the drive's firmware first, and then the dd command can do its job. The DeCSS library is not included by default a fresh Ubuntu installation, but there are instructions in the "Restricted Formats" section of the Ubuntu Wiki to install it. Be aware that using this software may carry legal consequences in some jurisdictions.

```
# apt install libdvd-pkg && dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
# apt install mplayer
# mplayer -dvd-device /dev/sr0 dvd:// -vo null -ao null -ss 10 -endpos 1
```

Now continue with the isoinfo and dd commands above

If the disc has both CSS encryption and additional protective measures such as fake bad blocks, then just unlocking the disc in the drive's firmware is not enough. Even though it is perfectly normal for such a disc to present unrecoverable errors when you attempt to read these fake bad blocks, the video content itself is actually completely intact. However, the normal dd command would likely abort at the first such block it encounters. ddrescue would be your friend in that case.

```
# apt install gddrescue
```

Use the instructions above to use a DeCSS-enabled player app to unlock the drive's firmware. Instead of moving on to isoinfo and dd, use ddrescue:

```
# ddrescue --no-scrape /dev/sr0 backup.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkisofs -pad -J -R -oDVD.iso -graft-points "/AUDIO_TS=/media/sr0/AUDIO_TS" "/VIDEO_TS=/media/sr0/VIDEO_TS"

mount -t iso9660 -o loop,ro DVD.iso /mnt

growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd=DVD.iso -speed=2
```

Comment: You may want to add exactly what this does to help the original poster in order to improve your answer.