# copy dvd to iso: brasero and k3b reports success but fails

Tags: iso, dvd, brasero, k3b

1. I started brasero and chose to copy the dvd to image file.
2. Brasero reported success.
3. Playing file in VLC, working flawlessly until unexpected exit at approx. 1 hour 28 mins 20 sec. No error message.
4. Trying the file in Movie Player. Unexpected exit at the same time, with this message: "An error occured. Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed."
5. Check that all libraries and ladidah from medibuntu repo are installed. They are.
6. Repeat steps 1 through 5.
7. Get the ppa https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools and replace wodim with cdrecord and geniosimage with mkisofs.
8. Throw out brasero and install k3b.
9. Repeat steps 1 through 5, with k3b not brasero.
10. Ask forums for help. This question is also posted at ubuntuforums.org.

How come both brasero and k3b reports success and then the iso is obviously broken? How to fix this problem?

This problem is similar, but not identical, to this one: [Ripping DVD to iso - Accurately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately)

Thankful for any and all input.

Edit: Tried

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=image_name.iso
```

and

```
ddrescue -v /dev/cdrom image_name.iso
```

Both of which renders an iso file that is not playing at all. So even though faulty, both brasero and k3b performs better than CLI in this case.

Comment: for dvd video there is dvdbackup

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dvd you have is protected by a software lock?
try nero too

Comment: I'd prefer to have it working on free software...

Comment: I recommend expanding this to provide information about how to use Nero on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ddrescue makes an encrypted image.  If you originally had a non-encrypted image (say from k3b) and you tried to play this in vlc, then the dvd keys for the iso file in your $USER/.dvdcss are for a non-encrypted DVD.  If you later use ddrescue to rip a new image, to play it you must remove the old keys for that image in $USER/.dvdcss and then try vlc again.

For problematic disks my best luck is to:

1. Insert the DVD in the drive
2. Play the DVD disk with vlc to get the keys into the
   drive (start to play and just use the bottom location
   slider to scan through the disk.  Do this for all the
   parts of the disk (main feature and all other parts).
3. Exit vlc.
4. Now run ddrescue -- I use (in bash)

   ```
   NAME=my_movie
   ddrescue -d -r2 -b2048 /dev/sr0 ${NAME}.iso ${NAME}_log
   ```
5. make sure you clear out the dvd keys. In `$HOME/.dvdcss` each DVD has a directory like `movie_name-date_string-disk_key`. For encrypted DVDs, The DVD disk has a non-zero disk key, the iso image has a zero disk key, but the contents of the directory are different if the iso image is encrypted or not SO clear out the image dir

   ```
   cd $HOME/.dvdcss
   rm -rf ./movie_name-date_string-0000000000
   ```
6. Now run vlc on the ddrescue image and see how you do.
   This has worked for most DVDs for me.  Some are more
   difficult as it seems there are errors on purpose in
   the navigation data area of the dvd and you have to
   let ddrescue work awhile to get enough good sectors
   in that area.
7. Note that the encrypted image CANNOT be used to write
   to DVD media, it can only be played off of the hard
   drive. (The encrypted disk keys exist in an area that
   cannot be written by DVD writers)