# How to create a DVD rip/ISO?

Tags: dvd, brasero, cd-ripping, dvd-backup

I am trying to create a back up of my "Chappelle's Show" DVD collection. I believe that creating an ISO would be the easiest thing to do. I have tried the `Brasero` but could not get it to work.

When using `Brasero` this error pops up:

```
All required applications and libraries are not installed. Please install the following manually and try again: libdvdcss.so.2 (library).
```

I tried to find this library but was unsuccessful. I have also tried the programs `DVD Rip` and `AcidRIP` and none work.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package and then install the libcss:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same error that did not work.

Comment: once again that did not work

Comment: @powell4076 After you do this, try restarting Brasero and try again.