# Making a backup copy of the DVD "Iron Man 2"

Tags: iso, dd, mp4, handbrake, dvd-backup

I am trying to make a backup copy of my DVD Iron Man 2 (I live in a country where it is OK).

This particular DVD has special tricks to prevent buyers from doing that ([see dicussion for Mac](http://www.macworld.com/article/1154702/99_title_dvd.html)).

I wanted to create an ISO file but [dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately) does not work:

```
$ dd if=/dev/dvd of=ironman2_backup.iso
dd: error reading ‘/dev/dvd’: Input/output error
12192+0 records in
12192+0 records out
6242304 bytes (6.2 MB) copied, 2.92969 s, 2.1 MB/s
```

I tried ripping it with Handbrake several times, but somehow the resulting MPG4 files either do not have any sound, or show only a fragment of the movie, like the intro.

**QUESTION:** How to backup this particular DVD?

Comment: What is your intended use of this .iso, just for playback or something else?

Comment: @doug: Yes, just for playback. I could mount it and use it like the normal DVD. I am also open to other formats  like MP4, actually that would be more convenient than ISO, I just thought ISO would be the easiest to create.

Comment: You can tell `dd` to ignore errors and continue... whether the resulting ISO will be usable or even readable, I do not know.

Comment: @muru: Do you mean `conv=noerror,sync`, or something else maybe?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul perhaps, I don't remember the exact options off-hand, but that seems to be it.

Comment: see here, describes a slight mis-use of dvdisaster. An encyrpted, stucture protected .iso is quite playable with some players like vlc (no need to mount). Some short extras may not be available but main menu, main movie should be. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6365060#post6365060