# Copying DVD's to my HDD

Tags: dvd

Now here's what I want to do - I have a lot of Movie DVD's and Bluerays.  I want to copy some of them to my HDD.  In Windows I know how to do this,  but not in Ubuntu.  With Windows u use a DvD Ripper,  what can u use in Ubuntu ?

I would be glad for a solution - thanx !!!

Comment: You could also use [AcidRip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/acidrip/).  `sudo apt-get install acidrip`

Comment: Say, @Mitch, you sure this is a dupe?  He's asking about ripping, while the question you referenced is talking about disk copying.

Comment: acidrip isn't available in 16.04 repos.

Comment: Have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/147800/ripping-dvd-to-iso-accurately

Comment: AcidRip may not be available in the repos, but it can be downloaded and installed from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/acidrip)

Comment: Sure.  Just bear in mind, he's not going to get it with the `apt-get install` command.

Comment: @anonymous2 It can still be installed, and used.

Comment: It absolutely can, and a jolly good thing, too.  :)

Comment: I you want a file which you can easily play (and copy to other devices too), I'd recommend using something like HandBrake to do the ripping. (It's in the repositories).

Comment: Thank you all very much.  I have installed Acidrip and it seems to work fine.